# Difference between pageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE and request object in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

```
pageContext.setAttribute("first","value1",pageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE);
```

and

```
request.setAttribute("first","value1");
```

Are these two the same or different? What is the purpose of `pageContext` and Page in JSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both these lines do the same thing, create a new attribute in request scope. If you look at `PageContext` class, it has a method [initialize](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/2.1/docs/jsp-2_1-pfd2/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html#initialize(javax.servlet.Servlet,%20javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20int,%20boolean)), in that it stores a reference to `request` object. So when you do `pageContext.setAttribute("first","value1",pageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE);`, it creates a new attribute in request scope.

> what is the purpose of pageContext and Page in JSP.

`pageContext` provides few other useful methods, such as `findAttribute`(inhertied method from [JspContext](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/2.1/docs/jsp-2_1-pfd2/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#findAttribute(java.lang.String))) which you can use when you don't know the scope in which attribute is stored.

`pageContext` is of type `javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext` which is an abstract class. Purpose of this class is to provide single object which exposes utility methods for both page authors and container implementers. As per [API DOC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/2.1/docs/jsp-2_1-pfd2/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html),

> - **Methods Intended for Container Generated Code**
>
> Some methods are intended to be used by the code generated by the
>   container, not by code written by JSP page authors, or JSP tag library
>   authors.
>
> The methods supporting lifecycle are initialize() and release()
>
> The following methods enable the management of nested JspWriter
>   streams to implement Tag Extensions: pushBody()
>
> - **Methods Intended for JSP authors**
>
> The following methods provide convenient access to implicit objects:
>
> getException(), getPage() getRequest(), getResponse(), getSession(),
>   getServletConfig() and getServletContext().
>
> The following methods provide support for forwarding, inclusion and
>   error handling: forward(), include(), and handlePageException().